# Mocha can't recognize React in import

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mocha.js, babeljs

I'm trying to incorporate Mocha into a React/Node application and I'm having some trouble calling react in my `test.js` file

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "blog_frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "front end app for react to connect to rails api",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --progress --color --watch --mode=development",
    "test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ],
    "plugins": "transform-es2015-modules-amd"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.5.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sinon": "^6.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.17.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mobx": "^5.0.4",
    "mobx-react": "^5.2.5",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.3",
    "purecss": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "react-css-modules": "^4.7.7",
    "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
    "react-ellipsis-text": "^1.0.0",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

`test/collection.test.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import {expect} from 'chai';

import Collection from '../app/components/Collection.js'

describe('Collection', function() {
  it('should have props for photos', function() {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Collection />); 
    expect(wrapper.props().photos).to.be.defined;
  });
});
```

`error message`

[image: error]

I've tried googling but most other posts have issues with the import keyword whereas mine specifically takes issue with React. I've tried installing different packages and tweaking settings in .babelrc but I haven't had any success. Any info is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ES modules are used in tests, they are not native Node .mjs modules and Mocha isn't configured to transpile .js files with Babel. There will be other problems with tested code, e.g. with class fields that aren't supported natively by Node.

Mocha should be configured to be used with Babel, e.g. as [the reference](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation#what-should-i-use-instead-then) suggests:

```
"test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --require babel-core/register"
```

Also  appropriate .babelrc configuration should be reachable in project root.

Comment: Well, I had a feeling i would run into other issues, but this led me to getting past the one i posted, so thanks.